# Stubbing out module dependencies with browserify

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, browserify

I'm using browserify as my module system.
I am trying to write a unit test for a module that looks a bit like this:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');

module.exports = function someFunc() {
  jQuery.ajax(...);
}
```

In my unit test, how can I stub out jQuery with my own mock?

When I `require(...)` the module from my unit test, I can only access the exported function, but none of the private members.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late probably but for future mockers - maybe one of these would help (I'm just about to try the first):

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify-swap
- https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify

Comment: Did you have any luck with these?

Comment: proxyquireify is the one to use for this scenario. It's not that well documented so took me a while to configure but is working great now. I will try and get a bit more added to the documentation if I ever get time.